# how do I DRY out this ruby if-then statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have the following code which seems verbose for what I want it to do:

```
if @initial_that.present?
  @that = @initial_that
  get_talk_api_response
else
  get_talk_api_response
end
```

It looks like I could make it DRY, but not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm sure there's a computer science name for this refactor, but you're calling get_talk_api_response in both branches, so put it outside the conditional instead:

```
if @initial_that.present?
  @that = @initial_that
end

get_talk_api_response
```

and then to make it look more ruby-like, per the hot comment:

```
@that = @initial_that if @initial_that.present?
get_talk_api_response
```

Comment: Even more idiomatic for Ruby, you could replace the conditional with `@that = @initial_that if @initial_that.present?`

Comment: And then put the get_talk_api_response right underneath?

Comment: yeah, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `present?` method, i assume your code is in a Rails app, so you could simply use [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence) method:

```
@that = @initial_that.presence || @that
get_talk_api_response
```

From the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence):

> **2.2 presence**
>
> The presence method returns its receiver if present?, and nil otherwise.

Comment: Unlike the OP's logic, this will tromp on whatever value is currently in `@that`. To use `presence`, I think you want to do `@that = @initial_that.presence || @that`.

Comment: @moveson Missed that, you are right, i'll edit the answer.

Comment: so I should use `@that = @initial_that.presence || @that`?

Comment: @mudasobwa On a second thought, maybe using `||=` is not a good fit since once `@that` is set, it will not care what `@initial_that.presence` returns.

Comment: @Angela Yes, i think is better that way.

Comment: The intent is that if there is a value for `!initial_that` substitute the value

Comment: @Angela Still yes, `@that = @initial_that.presence || @that` will substitute `@that` only if `@initial_that` has any value.

Comment: @Gerry yes, right, I was misled by “initial” buzzword.